# Drag-Drop Android Launcher / GridView Issue - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-gridview, android-launcher

I have a `gridView` I've created from an online example/tutorial and I'm trying to figure out how to change the behavior when a new item is dragged over a previously existing item in the `GridView`. Currently when a new item is dragged over the `gridView` it removes the current icon in place (leaving it with the red empty square [icon.png is a grid of empty squares the code uses as a background image])

I've poured through the example's source quite a few times and I can't figure out how to change the behavior of what happens when one item is dragged over the other

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Source code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6jCh_IJdtoFYWFJMlk5MHhlX3c/edit?usp=sharing

P.S.

I believe the issue may be in either the DragView or DropTarget class. (feel free to download the entire project - I've made the entire thing available for an easy download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at methods onDragEnter and onDragExit in ImageCell. Those two methods are the ones called as your finger passes over a cell on the grid. They set the background of the image view.

onDragEnter:
    int bg = mEmpty ? R.color.cell_empty_hover : R.color.cell_filled_hover;
    setBackgroundResource (bg);

onDragExit:
    int bg = mEmpty ? R.color.cell_empty : R.color.cell_filled;
    setBackgroundResource (bg);

The color definitions are in mycolor.xml.

Reference: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/

Comment: I have another question related to your tutorial... might you have a look? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911739/adding-a-textview-to-drag-and-drop-interface-android-java

Comment: @Bill Lahti, is it possible scrolling in gridview when user drag view try to drop the view that is not visible on the screen, so it required scrolling vertically. i have used below code. but it return droptarget "null".
int THRESHHOLD=10;int OFFSET=5;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         int height=gridview.getMeasuredHeight();
            float y=ev.getY();
            if (height - y < THRESHHOLD) {
             gridview.smoothScrollByOffset(OFFSET);
            } else if (height - y > height - THRESHHOLD) {
             gridview.smoothScrollByOffset(-OFFSET);
            }